# Problem in defining a module in omnetpp

Tags: c++, package, simulation

Hi
    I'm writing a project in omnet, but I'm stuck on defining my own module. On https://github.com/lbedogni/Basic-Broadcast-Simulation there is the full code. The problem is that i get the following error message:

```
<!> Error in module (cCompoundModule) scenario.host[0] (id=4) at event 
\#1, t=0: Class "basic::Flooding" not found -- perhaps its code was not 
linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in 
the case of modules and channels, with 
Define_Module()/Define_Channel().
```

But I defined it via `Define_Module()`.

I think it could possibly be a package related problem, but didn't find a solution. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with it, but from package.ned

// designate the NED package of this folder
package basic;

// namespace of module C++ classes
@namespace(basic);

@license(LGPL);

you need to be in namespace basic I guess?

And you flooding class is not defined within namespace basic?