# OMNeT++: Error in module during network setup: Class not found

Tags: eclipse-cdt, omnet++

I created my first OMNeT++/veins project, but can’t start the simulation. 
Can you help me?

**I would like to change my question - is there a simple way to create a project, similar to RSUExampleScenario of veins, not under veins/examples/myfolder, but in a separate project and workspace? And what steps must I do for it?**

I wanted to create a project similar to RSUExampleScenario from veins, but with other scenario and using other OMNeT++ modules. As I created my project under veins/examples/myfolder, and put my new .ned files under veins structure, it worked fine.

Now I created new project, including folders with .ned and c++/h files, like folder *connection* (Connection.ned, Connection.cc, Connection.h, package.ned) and folder *node* (CloudVehicleScenarioMessage.ned, Cloud.ned) and simulation folder *cloudvehiclehi* (omnetpp.ini).

When I start a simulation I receive the error:

*Error in module (cCompoundModule) CloudVehicleScenarioMessage (id=1) during network setup: Class "Connection" not found -- perhaps its code was not linked in, or the class wasn't registered with Register_Class(), or in the case of modules and channels, with Define_Module()/Define_Channel().*

I guess the NED files are loaded, but the classes in c++ files cannot be found, though I used *Define_Module*. Cloud is just a compound module, without any own c++ implementations, it creates no problems. Connection is a simple module, referring to class Connection.cc, where Define_Module() is called and causes the error while loading.
All my folders, like *node* or *connection* are included, as I can see under **Project->Properties->Paths and Symbols->Includes**.

I already tried to rebuild OMNeT++ (as told here  https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/3801609-234767834) and to define namespaces for my classes (as told here [Problem in defining a module in omnetpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385469/problem-in-defining-a-module-in-omnetpp)), but it didn’t help.

I proved my makefile and the folders were linked in (as told here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/omnetpp/Cl48hVgkbQ0).

CloudVehicleScenarioMessage.ned is my network in omnetpp.ini.

nodes/CloudVehicleScenarioMessage.ned:

```
package cloudbasedcsw.nodes;

import cloudbasedcsw.nodes.ScenarioMobility;
import cloudbasedcsw.nodes.Cloud;
import cloudbasedcsw.connection.Connection;

network CloudVehicleScenarioMessage extends ScenarioMobility
{
@display("bgb=540,555");
submodules:
    cloud[1]: Cloud {
        @display("p=150,140;b=10,10,oval");
    }
    con: Connection {
        @display("p=200,40;b=10,10,oval");
    }
}
```

ned file of module Connection:

connection/Connection.ned

```
package cloudbasedcsw.connection;

simple Connection{
    @class(CloudBasedCSW::Connection);
}
```

Class Connection, which can not be found:

connection/Connection.cc

```
#include <Connection.h>
#include <VehicleListener.h>
#include <iostream>
using CloudBasedCSW::Connection;

Define_Module(CloudBasedCSW::Connection);

void Connection::initialize(int stage){

}

void Connection::connectToCloud(cModule* node){
}

void Connection::disconnectFromCloud(cModule* node){
}
```

Connection.h

```
#ifndef CONNECTION_H_
#define CONNECTION_H_
#include <omnetpp.h>

namespace CloudBasedCSW{

class Connection: public cSimpleModule{
public:
    cModule* scenario;
    void connectToCloud(cModule* node);
    void disconnectFromCloud(cModule* node);
protected:
    virtual void initialize(int stage);
private:
    cModule* cloud;
    int currentId;
    int gateCloudInId;
    int gateCloudOutId;
};

}
#endif /* CONNECTION_H_ */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that your class `Connection` is in `CloudBasedCSW` C++ namespace. Therefore in `Connection.ned` you should change `@class(Connection);` to `@class(CloudBasedCSW::Connection);`.

Comment: Have you built your project? If not, go to **Project** and **Build Project**.

Comment: Let's check two things: 1) go to Run | Run Configurations..., select your configuration and tell me which option is checked: "opp_run" or "other"; 2) go to Project | Properties | OMNeT++ | Makemake, in the tree select folder which contains your source, then Options... | Target and tell me which type of target is selected (executable or shared library).

Comment: I chose op_run in run configuration, else I would have to choose an executable. But I want to have different simulations in my project, and there is only one executable in the main folder CloudBasedCSW.exe. As I understand, I need op_run and  run.sh (#!/bin/sh
../../run "$@") to run my simulation, like in veins RSUExampleScenario. Target type is executable. Is it false?

Comment: One more comment, I looked for target type in the makemake of the main project CloudBasedCSW. It includes folder with my simulation "cloudvehiclehi", which contains omnetpp, run.sh, and so on and is the run configuration. But "cloudvehiclehi" has no makemake.

Comment: In OMNeT++ there are 2 ways of preparing model: as an executable file or as a library (e.g. dll). To execute model prepared as the library the opp_run tool has been made because the dll file couldn't be started standalone.  In your situation target type executable means that compiled code goes into CloudBasedCSW.exe. However opp_run doesn't use executables. That explains why your simulation doesn't see compiled class Connection.  So I suggest: leave the target as executable and change Run Configuration to "other" and select `CloudBasedCSW.exe`.

Comment: I changed Run Configuration to other:CloudBasedCSW.exe and eliminated the namespaces and now it works. Thank you. And I can even have different run configurations in my project and it works with single .exe file, which I didn't thought previously.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to create a new project and run it, without this error. So, I will share my tutorial.

**How to create a OMNeT++ project, which uses veins.**

1. Create omnet++ project myproject File->new->OMNeT project->Empty project with 'src' and 'simulations' folders
2. Veins must be imported into the workspace in order to use it: Import-> Existing projects into workspace->
3. Add veins to Project->Properties->Project References
4. Put your .ned and c++/h files in folder src
5. Put omnetpp.ini and all sumo configuration files in folder simulations
6. Create run configuration simulation, with working directory myproject/simulations and Simulation->Executable->Other: with exe file from /myproject/src/myproject

**Remark:**  Don't use namespaces in your c++ files, corresponding to .ned files, because the classes in c++ files would not be found (
*Error in module (cCompoundModule) CloudVehicleScenarioMessage (id=1) during network setup: Class "vehicle" not found* ).

For Example you have vehicle.ned and vehicle.cc. vehicle.cc 
includes a class mynamespace::vehicle. vehicle.ned wouldn't know that vehicle lies under namespace mynamespace. Only if a class is defined in ned file via @class(mynamespace::vehicle), it can be found.

Comment: ad namespaces: using @namespace() in .ned file may fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

A easy way to correct this error is copying the .cc or all c++ files into a veins/src/ folder. Using this technique you compiler recognize you class.